# Raycast using object Ids not working : threeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I'm trying to assign different standard materials for different parts of the model through ray casting, using its object ID as reference. However, when I try to apply more than one material for a different id of the same model, all the objects are showing up the same material. unable to differentiate between IDs.

The code for the same is below.

```js
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
if (intersects.length > 0) {

  for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
    if (intersects[i].object.id) {

      intersects[i].object.material = material1; /* standrad material */
      intersects[i].object.material.needsUpdate = true;
    }
  }

    /* I'm using the buttons to change the materials */

    $('.btn1').click(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
        intersects[i].object.material = material2;
        intersects[i].object.material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });

    $('.btn2').click(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
        intersects[i].object.material = material3;
        intersects[i].object.material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to structure something like this:

```js
function materialSwitchingTest(renderer,camera){

    var mouseVec = new THREE.Vector3();
    var mouse2D = new THREE.Vector3();
    var rawMouse2D = new THREE.Vector3();
    var intersections = []

    /* I'm using the buttons to change the materials */
    $('.btn1').click(function() {
        if(intersections.length>0) intersections[0].object.material = material1
    });

    $('.btn2').click(function() {
        if(intersections.length>0) intersections[0].object.material = material2
    });

    window.onmousedown=(e)=>{
        if(event.target !== renderer.domElement.parentElement)return
        var mx = event.layerX;
        var my = event.layerY;
        rawMouse2D.set(mx, my, 0);
        mouse2D.x = (mx / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
        mouse2D.y = -(my / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse2D,camera)
intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
    }
}


materialSwitchingTest( yourRenderer, yourCamera )
```

Comment: thanks your approach helped me to reach mine. kudos.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this, I had to change my logic a bit to suit the requirement. here is what I did.

```js
if (intersects.length > 0) {


  if (intersected1 != intersects[0].object) {
    if (intersected1)
      intersected1 = intersects[0].object;
    intersected1.material = materialin;
    intersected1.material.needsUpdate = true;
  } else {
    if (intersected1) intersected1.material = material1;
    intersected1.material.needsUpdate = true;

    intersected1 = null;
  }

  $('.btn1').click(function() {
    intersected1.object.material = material1;
  });

  $('.btn2').click(function() {
    intersected1.material = material2;
  });
```